# jquery load function

Tags: jquery, load

i write following code

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#disp').load('index.php', function(){
         $('#lobar').hide();
       });

    });
  </script>
```

what i need to load index.php on page load in to div named: dis

Thanks

Comment: You asked about 'dis' element, but in your source you reference the 'disp' one. Make sure what the name of your div.

Answer (score 3):

```
$(function() {
    $('#disp').load('index.php', {}, function(){
        $('#lobar').hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The load() function takes 3 arguments but you are only passing in 2. Look at the documentation for the load function at [this link](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/load#urldatacallback). I think you want to pass a null as the 2nd parameter to achieve the results you want.

```
$('#disp').load('index.php', null, function(){
   $('#lobar').hide();
 });
```

Comment: The second and third params are optional and you may pass the third one without the second param. See source of jQuery library.